# How can I use "having"?

Tags: american-english

I want to make question sentence like this.
"What does it have a meaning xxx ?"
Or
"What does it is having a meaning xxx ?"

I have no idea what I do use question sentence with having.

Comment: What kind of answers are you looking for when you ask either of those questions? Both sound ungrammatical and I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want to know (when you ask the question).

Comment: To making grammatical sentence. And I don't know when did you answer my question?

Comment: Are you asking for the meaning of a word when you say these questions?

Comment: I'm guessing here. It seems like you want to say, "What does xxx mean?" or maybe "What is the meaning of xxx?" or maybe "What if it means xxx?" or maybe "What is it, a word that means xxx?" I think there might be some other possibilities, too. Not sure.

Comment: @Siliance : I am just asking the sentence structure with "having mean".

Comment: This use of *have* is stative and can't appear in the progressive: "What meaning **does** this **have**?" but not ＊"What meaning **is** this **having**?" (ungrammatical)

Comment: @ snailboat : thanks that is what I want answer. "What meaning does this have?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the verb "have" is used as a stative verb that describes a state or condition rather than an activity, it's not used in the progressive tenses such as  I am having a car, I am owning a house, I am liking it, I am understanding you, etc.

So forget about using the present participle "having" in these sentences. You can say "What meaning does it have?" or more simply "What does it mean?".